# How to extend felogin's locallang?

Tags: localization, typo3

How is it possible to add translations of strings to the felogin plugin? I slowly start to get the convention for templates (directing to the modified templates in the plugin's typoscript configuration) but that does not work with the locallang. The original messages are in English in the xlf format, located in the plugin's folder. I know this can be done in TypoScript but I do not like to have the strings defined so incosistently. (I guess modifying that original file is not the proper way.)

Answer (score 7):

Overriding labels by TypoScript is the way to go. Manually editing the l10n files is a really bad idea - these files are overwritten on updating the translations. If the extension gets an update and new labels are added, you will want to perform the updates.

The change from XML files for translation to the XLIFF format didn't change anything in the best practise you should use for adjusting labels according to your needs. It's just another format with a standardized translation server (Pootle) that (in theory) allows some special features like e.g. plural forms.

Conclusion: Use TypoScript.

For the default language (no config.language set) use:

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1._LOCAL_LANG.default {
   key = value
}
```

For a specific language, e.g. German, use

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1._LOCAL_LANG.de {
   key = value
}
```

Comment: I do not like the editing files inside the plugin too. But I wanted to avoid your TypoScript solution as well as there is a new standard for translations adopted by Typo3 (xlf) so what is the use of it when I end up translating via TypoScript (not mentioning the mixing of two ways of translating at the same time)?

Comment: I edited my answer to answer your question about xlf.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use the following code:

*ext_tables.php*, e.g. of your theme extension with

```
   $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['locallangXMLOverride']['EXT:felogin/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf'][] = 'EXT:theme/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_felogin.xlf';
```

and in this file you can use something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<xliff version="1.0">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2015-06-30T21:14:27Z">
        <header>
            <description>Language labels for felogin</description>
        </header>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="permalogin">
                <source>An diesem Rechner angemeldet bleiben</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="ll_forgot_header">
                <source>Passwort vergessen?</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="ll_welcome_header">
                <source>Sie betreten den Händlerbereich</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="ll_welcome_message">
                <source>Bitte loggen Sie sich ein.</source>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Comment: Thank you, Georg. That’s the trick to replace the XLIFF file in the standard language. What about the language-specific XLIFF files in _typo3conf/l10n/xx/felogin_? How can I replace these?

Comment: I found the answer myself: Just put your translated XLIFF files (_xx.locallang\_felogin.xlf_) into the same directory the standard file is in. (“All caches” may have to be cleared after that.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BE language module to download preconfigured locallangs for every language you need. 
The files are stored in e.g. typo3conf/l10n/de/fe_login.

You can edit these files manually in l10n to get your own strings inside or use an extension like snowbabal to do the editing inside a BE module.

Comment: Don't these translations in the l10n folder (possibly modified by me) get overwritten at some occassions (like plugin update or add/removal)?

Comment: No, an extension update normally doenst affect l10n folder. Would most likely be overwritten if you download the language again via TYPO3 backend.